# How to traverse website, get all console

Tags: javascript, html, web-testing

Say I have a website with the following pages:

page1.html,
page2.html,
page3.html

for each one of these pages, load the page, and get the console logs.

Comment: What "console logs" are you referring to? If you're referring to what `console.log` produces, those are temporary aren't "gettable" afaik. Those are mainly for troubleshooting.

Comment: if i were to console.log('some string');

Comment: I updated my comment. Read it again.

Comment: Yea. I posted by comment prior to you updating your comment

Comment: I'm just wondering why exactly my question got down-voted twice. Truly am curious as I am trying to be a better member of the community....

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question shows very little effort. You haven't shown any attempt to answer this on your own before asking here. If you need more "permanent" client-side logging, use LocalStorage.

Comment: I'm using the jQuery migrate api, and thought it'd be awesome to automate visiting each route. 

The api automatically logs it to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iframe and load your next html files changing `.src` with `onload` event. The `console.log`s from each html file will be shown in your console.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var iter = 0;
var myLinks = ['page1.html','page2.html','page3.html']; //replace with your correct existing urls
iframe.src = myLinks[0];

iframe.onload = function(){
 iter++;
 if(iter===myLinks.length) return;
 iframe.src = myLinks[iter];
};
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
```